# listObjects() doesnt give full list of objects in a bucket in s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the commonPrefixes of a bucket from amazon s3. I am using following code to get the list of all objects:

```
ObjectListing listing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix("used/").withDelimiter("/"));
for (String name : listing.getCommonPrefixes()) 
{
    System.out.println(name);
    objectNames.add(name);
}
System.out.println("\n\n\nSize: " + objectNames.size());
```

But it just prints some of the commonPrefixes. There are more than 2000 prefixes, but it just prints 950. How can I get all the prefixes?

Comment: Do you mean `objectNames.size() > 2000` but only 950 lines get printed?

Comment: No, there are more than 2000 keys in that bucket, but getCommonPrefixes() gives just 950 keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ObjectListing` is only going to contain at most 1000 objects at a time. When you call `getCommonPrefixes` it is only returning the common prefixes for those 1000 objects. You need to check the ObjectListing's `isTruncated()` method to determine if there are more records, and then use the `getNextMarker()` method along with subsequent `listObjects` calls to get the remaining object records, and the common prefixes for those objects.

Comment: wrapping the code in `while (listing.isTruncated())` did the task. And `listing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing)` brought in the next 1000 prefixes.